# How does Google search for blog on my website?

Tags: google, blog

I just checked my site with WooRank and it says there is no blog on your website. 
How does Google search for blog on my website?
Is it enough if I create a blogspot page, or I should make something more advanced?

Comment: I would use WooRank as a guideline more than anything as I've noticed there are some inconsistencies with the reporting that hasn't picked up blogs on a number of my sites despite being searchable by google etc..

Comment: WooRank sometimes detects a blog when there is no blog.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have atom or RSS feeds in meta tags, i'm sure Google looks for many more signals than WooRank to determine if a site has a blog or is a Blog. Especially since they have bots dedicated to crawling blogs. If Google sees your site and webmaster tools says there's nothing wrong I don't think you should be worrying about what any other website says.

Answer (score 0):

WooRank checks **www.yoursite.com/blog** to find a blog for your site.

Comment: Can you provide a reference? This is not a reliable method and is certainly not the only method that WooRank uses.

Comment: @w3d I found in a post comment here [http://www.seomoz.org/q/benefits-put-my-blog-inside-website-or-outside-the-website](http://www.seomoz.org/q/benefits-put-my-blog-inside-website-or-outside-the-website) 
however it works for me.